# Function returning id of an element if position of the component is given on the screen

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android . So please help me . Could some one please tell is there any function that returns the id of a component in the screen when the position is specified . For ex : ( Consider a button is in the position 300,400 (pixels) . Is there any function that returns the id of the component when the position is specified , Consider the id of the button as **R.id.bt1** on passing the position of the button say **300,400** . It must return the id of the button)

Comment: Can you give a use case for this?  There may be another way to accomplish what you are looking to do.  If not, my best guess would be to loop through all views and check their positions.

Comment: Could u please get me a sample code .

Answer (score 0):

can you explain why you need the id? like what your doing with it?
usually the id is how you find it with findViewById. are you adding it programmatically? or is it in xml?

if its programmatic you will need to add the id via java before you can fetch it. kind of redundant.

if its in xml i can think of no real reason to need the coordinates.....
let me see the code you have, preferably the activity itself?

Comment: The one i m trying to develop is a puzzle where the objects need to be moved and gotta be arranged in a correct format . So i gotta loop through each and every objects in the required position whether they are placed in correct position or not .